# MS Word VBA: Compile Error: Method or data member not found

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the code below. When I run it, MS VBA window gives me a compile error: Method or data member not found

Can't run the Macro because of the error.

I tried different versions of Word, renaming HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Data

My document name is ABCTrial.

This is my first code and I suspect I am doing something very basic wrong, like document or Macro name. I ran the code through debugger and it seems fine.

```
Sub FormatDocument()
    ' Remove page numbers
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).PageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = False
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).PageNumbers.NumberStyle = wdPageNumberStyleNone
   
    ' Remove headers and footers
    Dim sec As Section
    For Each sec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        sec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = ""
        sec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text = ""
        sec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range.Text = ""
        sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = ""
        sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text = ""
        sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range.Text = ""
    Next sec
   
    ' Change layout to Landscape and margins to Narrow
    With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
        .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
        .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5)
    End With
   
    ' Remove all manual page breaks
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Execute FindText:="^m", ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
   
    ' Remove all instances of "please"
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = " please "
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
   
    ' Remove all extra spaces between paragraphs
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "^013{2,}"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
   
    ' Find all numbered content and apply "RFI Black left" style
    Dim p As Paragraph
    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If p.Range.ListFormat.ListType <> wdListNoNumbering Then
            p.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("RFI Black left")
        End If
    Next p
   
End Sub
```

Comment: A [`Section`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.section) object has no `PageNumbers` property.

Comment: I'm not a Word person, but are you missing a `.Footers(...)` perhaps?

Comment: You can avoid mistakes like this by using IntelliSense as you type your code. Or you can look up the properties you want to use in the Object Browser (press F2 to launch) and online documentation (F1). There is example code in the documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.pagenumbers.restartnumberingatsection